# Cytoscape.js, display round shape on top of the edge

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape.js model, where edges between nodes represent different relations.

I want to have possibility to display something like round shape or button in the middle of the edge, where user could click and get popup to change the relationship type.

So far I see in base package there is no option to display round shape.

I am using dagre layout, and this is my current edge configuration:

```
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          width: 1,
          "font-size": "20px",
          //opacity: "0.5",
          label: "data(type)",
          color: function(ele) {
            return getEdgeColor(ele.data("type"));
          },

          "line-color": function(ele) {
            return getEdgeColor(ele.data("type"));
          },
          "target-arrow-color": function(ele) {
            return getEdgeColor(ele.data("type"));
          },
          "curve-style": "straight",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
        }
      },
```

Could you recommend me any easy solution?

Comment: Please provide any code of what you have tried so far and indicate where you are stuck or need help.

Comment: Hi RyanNerd, I added the details. However, my question is quite easy. I think what I want is not delivered in standard package, so either there is an extension from someone else I could use, or hopefully somehow standard cytoscape package allows it and I just missed how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround for this (the editation works on the whole edge, the dot is just for the looks:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'height': '60px',
        'width': '60px'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
      'font-size': "40px",
        'label': "\u2022",
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'data(arrow)'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n1',
          arrow: 'triangle'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n2',
          arrow: 'triangle'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n3',
          arrow: 'triangle'
        }
      },
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'concentric',
    minNodeSpacing: 140,
  }
});

cy.cxtmenu({
  selector: 'edge',
  menuRadius: 90,
  commands: [{
    content: 'Direction',
    select: function(edge) {
      edge.move({
        source: edge.target().id(),
        target: edge.source().id()
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.cxtmenu-disabled {
  opacity: 0.333;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape@3.10.1/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cxtmenu@3.1.1/cytoscape-cxtmenu.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I use the ctx-menu extension here (right click on edge to open menu) and the dot is just an unicode character.